# How can we compute the integral of a Laplacian of a radial function over an open ball

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives, laplacian

Let $B_R\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ be an open ball with radius $R>0$ centered at $0$  and $f\in C^0\left(\overline{B_R}\to\mathbb{R}\right)$ be a radial function, i.e. $f(x)=f(r)$ with $r:=\left\|x\right\|_2$ being the euclidean distance of $x$.

Moreover, let $u\in C^2\left(\overline{B_R}\to\mathbb{R}\right)$ be the (unique and radial) solution of $$\left\{\begin{matrix}-\Delta u&\equiv &f&\text{in}&B_R\\u&\equiv&0&\text{in}&\partial B_R \end{matrix}\right.\tag{ED}$$ Now, let $\varphi\in C^2\left(\overline{B_R}\to\mathbb{R}\right)$ with $\varphi\equiv 0$ in $\partial B_R$. I really would like to exactly understand why $(1)$ and $(2)$ hold in

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\int_{B_R}f\varphi\;&\stackrel{(\text{ED})}{=}-\int_{B_R}\Delta u\varphi\\
&\stackrel{(1)}{=}\int_{B_R}\nabla u\nabla\varphi-\int_{\partial B_R}\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}\underbrace{\varphi}_{=0}\\
&\stackrel{(2)}{=}-\int_{B_R} u\Delta\varphi+\int_{\partial B_R}\underbrace{u}_{=0}\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial\nu}\\
&=-\int_{B_R}u\Delta\varphi
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $\frac{\partial}{\partial\nu}$ denotes a normal derivative (and I don't understand what $\nu$ exactly is).

Comment: (1) holds because of Green's first identity (which follows from the divergence theorem) and (2) holds again by Green's first identity (the expression in (2) is equal to $\int_{B_R} \nabla u \cdot \nabla \varphi$).  The symbol $\nu$ represents the outward unit normal to $B_R$. The normal derivative is a directional derivative: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \nu} := \nabla f \cdot \nu$